PERN App Deployment | Deploying Client, Server and Database on one Heroku server
I've created an E-commerce app using the following technologies:

Node
Express
Nest
PostgreSQL
React

My Front-End and Back-End runs like two different apps.
Its a basic app with 20-25 products and I want to deploy it with minimum cost, I can expect 15-20 users at a time and I want the app to run all time.

Can I deploy my Front-End, Back-End, and PostgreSQL on Heroku's Basic Plan which cost $7, all three on one server?

What are other reliable options if I'm on a budget and needs a reliable platform?


